# Using str.split for pandas dataframe values based on parentheses location

Tags: python, pandas, split

Let's say I have the following dataframe series df['Name'] column:

```
         Name
       'Jerry'
  'Adam (and family)'
'Paul and Hellen (and family):\n'
'John and Peter (and family):/n'
```

How would I remove all the contents in Name after the first parentheses?

```
df['Name']= df['Name'].str.split("'(").str[0]
```

doesn't seem to work and I don't understand why?

The output I want is

```
         Name
       'Jerry'
        'Adam'
    'Paul and Hellen'
    'John and Peter'
```

so everything after the parentheses is deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution with [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) - is necessary escape `(` by `\`:

```
df['Name']= df['Name'].str.split("\s+\(").str[0]
print (df)
               Name
0           'Jerry'
1             'Adam
2  'Paul and Hellen
3   'John and Peter
```

Solution with `regex` and [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df['Name']= df['Name'].str.replace("\s+\(.*$", "")
print (df)
               Name
0           'Jerry'
1             'Adam
2  'Paul and Hellen
3   'John and Peter
```

`\s+\(.*$` means replace from optional `whitespace`, first `(` to the end of string `$` to `""` - empty string.

Comment: so what does "( \().*$"  actually mean?

Comment: I am not regex expert, so I try explain it how I understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression:

```
>>> import re
>>> str = 'Adam (and family)'
>>> result = re.sub(r"( \().*$", '', str)
>>> print result
Adam
```

Comment: This applies to str and not dataframe object ... TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: Use `str.replace`, it allows to use regular expression : `Replace occurrences of pattern/regex in the Series/Index with some other string. Equivalent to str.replace() or re.sub().` see more : http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html#pandas.Series.str.replace